# Pronunciation of 部屋

Tags: pronunciation

This is a question I had for some time: can 部屋 be pronounced as "hea", or it's always pronounced as "heya", with an audible YA sound?

I'm asking this because more often than not I hear it without the Y sound (like [here](https://forvo.com/word/%E9%83%A8%E5%B1%8B/#ja) in the pronunciation by akitomo, while that from molio clearly has that sound): usually I can hear it in other words,  but I know some sound can be hard to hear if the listener isn't used to it (like nasalized vowels), so I'm not sure if it's an irregular (or imprecise) pronunciation, or if it's just I can't hear that specific sound in that specific word.

Comment: Hmm.. I still hear ヘヤ, but the palatal approximant [j] is indeed weaker in akitomo's  pronunciation, but I think it's still there.

Comment: I too still hear the "y".  It sounds very typical to me.  It also sounds like it's being pronounced further toward the back of the tongue and the back roof of the mouth.  If you're a native English speaker, this can be initially hard to pick up since English tends to pronounce "e" more as "ey".  But in Japanese "e" is never pronounced this way.

Comment: Then I guess I just have to get used to it, thanks. @A.Ellett I'm Italian; as far as I understand our and Japanese **e** are very similar, but something may be different enought that I'm just not used to sounds like that in 部屋.

Comment: I'm actually curious whether there are any non-gairaigo words that have the vowel combination "ea".  Right now, I can't think of any.

Comment: @A.Ellett there seem to be someone, but at least according to Jisho most of them not common; as common, it lists 家主{いえあるじ}. Edit: it doesn't seem to accept the link, try looking for `*えあ*` on Jisho.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to cause any problem in listening comprehension.

Comment: @A.Ellett - Even gairaigo words like ヘア and ケア can be pronounced with the [j] sound.

Comment: [部屋]{へや}, [欅]{けやき} both are the same kind to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it is true that //eja// and //ea// tend to be neutralized in fast speech (e.g. 部屋タイプ vs ヘアタイプ), the sound clips on that forvo page all sound appropriate to me.

It is a conjecture, but since you said you are Italian, the standard Italian language has a 4-level vowel height distinction; that means you have an open //ɛ// (in *vento* "wind") and a closed //e// (in *venti* "twenty") between //i// and //a//. Japanese, in contrary, only has 3-level height, with only //e// that stands in the very middle ([[e̞]]) between //i// and //a//. It means the Japanese language tolerates a bit more open //i// than the Italian counterpart. In the sound clips I hear two distinct Japanese sounds //e// and //j// (which is nothing but //i//) after //h// and before //a//, but if you only hear monotonic //e//, you are perhaps recognizing both the starting and ending articluations within the range of Italian //e//.

(By the way strawberrybrown's pronunciation sounds most standard to me among those clips, and molio's one sounds overly exaggerated.)

Comment: I am not sure I understand this part: "which is nothing but /i/". Did you mean "which is nothing like /i/"?

Comment: That's interesting, thanks; as a side note, Italian do also have /j/, like in *ieri* / /'jeri/ ("yesterday"), also mid-word. In strawberrybrown's pronunciation I kinda hear it, "kinda" because I'm not sure I'd recognize it not knowing it's there, but I do hear it differently with respect to akimoto's.

Comment: @Mauro When I listen to Italian examples of //j// on Forvo, they sound quite "strong", that is, more squeezed and I even hear friction at the word initial. Japanese //j// is simply (Japanese) //i// as consonant, so I think much less intensive than what you're ready to hear.

Comment: @EddieKal "nothing but /i/" was perhaps an overstatement but I wanted to say they have little difference in sound value.

Comment: @broccolifacemask yes, I think our /j/ is always stronger than in 部屋, also mid-word (like https://forvo.com/word/saio/#it - "tunic (today, especially of a priest)" - and https://forvo.com/word/pi%C3%B9/#it - "more").